# Solve the equation $\cos(x) + h\cos(hx) = 0$, where $h\in\mathbb{R}$

Tags: trigonometry

I have this equation:

$$\cos(x) + h\cos(hx) = 0$$ where $h$ is a real constant.

I want to find all $x$ for which this is true; but I don't know how to isolate $x$.

Comment: What have you tried? Please add it to the OP by editing. Also is $h$ an integer?

Comment: What does the $h$ mean?

Comment: h is just a constant, sorry about that

Comment: An integer constant?

Comment: Sorry, edited all that.

Comment: You guys are really fast at editing everything! I'm a noobie here, sorry for all the mistakes!

Comment: I guess you need, "in general", a numerical approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**IT IS WRONG** : indeed $f(x)=0$ does not imply $f'(x)=0$

---

If you differentiate twice the equality relatively to $x$, you get :
$$\cos(x) + h\cos(hx) = 0\Rightarrow-\cos(x)-h^3\cos(hx)=0$$
So adding the two equalities we get :
$$h\cos(hx)-h^3\cos(hx)=0\Rightarrow h(\cos(hx)-h^2\cos(hx))=0$$
So if $h\neq0$ :
$$\cos(hx)-h^2\cos(hx)=0\Rightarrow(1-h^2)\cos(hx)=0$$
So if $h\neq\pm1$ :
$$\cos(hx)=0$$
You should be able to finish.
**Note** : Following this reasonning you will find possible solutions you will have to verify that they are indeed solutions. And you also need to treat the cases $h=0$ and $h=\pm1$ but they are rather easy.

Comment: $\cos\left(\,x\,\right) + 2\cos\left(\,2x\,\right) = 0 \implies 4\cos^{2}\left(\,x\,\right) + \cos\left(\,x\,\right) - 2 = 0 \implies \cos\left(\,x\,\right) = {-1 \pm \sqrt{33} \over 8}$ which doesn't agree with your answer.

Comment: I have no idea where my proof fail but I need to go, I will take a look at it tomorrow